# Sorting an array in date order causes crash on device

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, crash, nsdate

I have an array storing different dates:

```
var Dates_Array = [String]()
```

I then have an extension that converts strings to NSDate:

```
    extension String{
    var StringToDate:NSDate {
        let df = NSDateFormatter()
        df.dateStyle = .LongStyle
        df.timeStyle = .NoStyle
        return (df.dateFromString(self))!
    }
}
```

This is the code that sorts the array:

```
self.Ordered_Dates_Array = self.Dates_Array.sort { ($0 ).StringToDate.compare(($1 ).StringToDate) == .OrderedAscending}
```

In the simulator all of this code works as expected. But when I ran it on a device the app crashes, here is an image of the error message:

[image]

When I comment out the code that sorts the array everything works as expected. So what is causing my app to crash on a device but not the simulator?

**Edit:**

This is what Dates_Array looks like:

["December 24, 2016", "September 14, 2016", "September 19, 2016", "November 19, 2016"]

My device Time Zone is London. Language = English and Calendar = Gregorian.

Comment: nil, you have nil somewhere, go line by line and just check where

Comment: One or more of your strings can't be converted to a Date using your date formatter. BTW - that approach will rarely work since the `dateStyle` will be different for every locale and even based on settings the user has made in the Settings app.

Comment: So why can one or more of the strings not be converted to a date? Why would this work in the simulator but not on the device? And if all of the dates are long style, then it should still work?

Comment: You need to update your question with samples of the strings you are trying to convert. And you need to tell us what locale (country and language) you are using on the device causing the problem. It would also help to know how the strings were created to begin with.

Comment: Question updated...

Comment: How are the strings created? Where do they come from?

Comment: In the UK, the long date format will be more like "24 December 2016", not "December 24, 2016" (which is more of a USA format).

Comment: Thanks!!! The date format was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I had my dates written in the United States, but my region on my device is set to United Kingdom, which has a different date styles. Thanks @rmaddy for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `return (df.dateFromString(self))!` with:

```
if let dateString = df.dateFromString(self) {
    return dateString
} else {
    //Handle situations where the string can't be formatted as date
    return "Can't convert to date"
}
```

Now you can know which string can't be converted.

Comment: Apparently none of them can be converted, yet they could in the simulator.